# Mute all other application's volume using java

Tags: java, c++, c, audio, system-calls

I am looking for a solution to mute all applications(like vlc, windows media player or some other player) using a java program and I doubt whether it's possible using java?.

PS: I **dont** want to mute the system master volume. I just want to mute the application which is playing at that point of time.(whatever applicatin it may be).

I tried calling some third party tools from my java program which mutes some players like vlc,windows media player etc.But it is not the ideal solution as there may be other apps which are out of scope of that tool.

Are there any specific languages(like C/C++ ) which does that task so that I can call that program from java (Possible solution.Open to other ideas , solutions)

So any ideas??

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977263/how-to-create-a-mute-option

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but you should check out Java's Sound API http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html

Comment: Not part of your question, but if you do end up wanting to call C++ code from Java code, use [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) rather than running an external executable.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316791(v=vs.85).aspx) for the Audio API system calls which may be able to achieve what you want. I've assumed your platform is Windows since you mentioned Windows Media Player. I believe those APIs are only available in Vista and above.

Comment: I haven't received any answer yet. Still waiting for the solution.